# Maximum number of external IP addresses per machine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

What is the maximum number of external IP addresses that can be assigned to a machine on Google Compute Engine? I found the [AWS limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI) but I can't find the same for Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 1):

the [Resource Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas) and [Interconnect Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/quotas) do not state any limit for external IP addresses, therefore they are available as good as unlimited, but still may be limited by two factors: a) by the availability of the resource-type in the region and b) how many of them you are able to pay. in case you may wonder how many of them one can assign to a single instance; this might be 4000-5000 (based upon reports), until the network stack becomes unstable vs. the theoretical limit of 4 294 967 294 (- 2). one possibly can only estimate that value, because the hardware configuration also plays a role there; with multiple virtual NIC it should be able to take a multiple of IPs.

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#max-interfaces the maximum number of virtual NICs is 8. How many IP addresses can we use per NIC?

Comment: Have a look at [forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding). Ie forwarding external IP’s to instances. There’s a limit of 50 rules per project as per docs. (Whatever ‘project’ means in this context). Not sure if this can be used for outbound traffic as well

Comment: one can forward sub-net wise from the load balancer: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/create
... while in general the external IPs matter for the load-balancer while one is in place; unless having to access the instances directly from the public network. that is 50 ranges, not 50 addresses, with 50 rules.

Comment: @Geert-Jan Fowarding rules are not relevant because I need multiple outgoing IP addresses. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52224794/14731 for more information.