# How to assign multiple outgoing IPs addresses to a single instance on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

This question is the AWS counterpart to [How to assign multiple outgoing IPs addresses to a single instance on GCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52224794/14731)

I'd like to initiate outgoing HTTP requests from multiple IP addresses from a single AWS instance. How can one assign multiple external IP addresses to a single instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for something that will automatically utilize multiple IP addresses for your instance's outgoing network traffic, I don't think that exists. You would need to assign multiple public IPs to the EC2 instance via Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs), which the instance operating system will bind to multiple network interfaces. Then the software you are running on the EC2 instance would need to be aware of all the network interfaces and do some sort of random or round-robin algorithm to pick which interface to send each outgoing request to.

Comment: Correct, I just want to assign multiple instances to a single instance and have the software choose which interface to use for each outgoing request. Thank you for pointing this out.